# Will SQL Server 2014 not cause problems with a SQL Server 2008 DB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I will be doing development work on a SQL Server 2008 database.

I am planning on buying a copy of SQL Server for this project. I am wanting to verify that the latest SQL Server version, 2014, won't cause any problems in the following scenario:

- Pull,(Backup) copy of database from 2008 (the source)
- Restore database to my local 2014
- Make changes
- Pull,(Backup) copy of database from 2014
- Restore over the existing 2008 database (which was the source) with the copy from 2014

I am aware that I won't be able to utilize any of the newer features that 2014 might offer that aren't available in 2008... I just want to know that it won't blow anything up.

NOTE: I don't have access to the SQL Server 2008 DB server right now... additionally I don't yet have the SQL Server 2014 software; I have SQL Server 2012 express.

I have an answer for this, just export as SQL statements (thanks to comments below). The better question is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/restoring-a-backup-to-an-older-version-of-sql-server?lq=1)

Comment: You can't back up your 2014 database and restore it over the existing 2008 database on the source server, unless you also upgrade the source server. You can upgrade, but you can't downgrade.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand. So, assuming I am understanding correctly, I have to buy 2008 for this project.

Comment: No, there are plenty of other ways to migrate your local changes to your source server, even if it has a lower version. [Some ideas here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/restoring-a-backup-to-an-older-version-of-sql-server), also see schema/data comparison tools, like those from Red Gate.

Comment: Thanks again @AaronBertrand. There is a great point on that page, I can just export the actual SQL to re-create the database, in whatever version I want... had forgotten about that... I'll make sure I have no problems going from 2012 express to 2008/2005 that way and report back. 
Feel free to provide that link as an answer if you want so I can select it as THE answer. 
Thanks again!

Comment: You will find [**this answer**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55055/how-to-move-a-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-sql-server-2005/55063#55063) useful.

Comment: Thanks @Kin. I'ts been a few years so that is a good reminder.