# Attached database to SQL Server 2016 and now won't work in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL Server 2014 database (on a portable hard drive) which I had to attach to a SQL Server 2016 machine using the normal attach method.

However, since attaching it to that computer, it no longer works on the SQL Server 2014 computer even though I didn't change the compatibility level or anything else for that matter.

I'm now stuck because SQL Server 2016 will not work on Windows 7 machines which is what all the other computers run on. I just happened to attach it on a laptop running Windows 10 and SQL 2016 thinking it wouldn't be a problem.

Is there any way to reverse this situation? I'm not able to get any good information from the error screen in management studio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you attached the mdf file(s) to the SQL Server 2016 instance the database was [upgraded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189625.aspx). The files were marked as being of the new version. There is [no downgrade path](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4908/36809) in SQL Server.

The best option is restore from backup. Else, you many be able to script the schema and data and build a new database on the 2014 instance which is identical to the previous one. [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/)'s one way of achieving this. Be aware of the things the tool may not script, like users, permissions, synonyms etc.

See also: [How to move a database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2005](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55055/how-to-move-a-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-sql-server-2005/55063#55063)