# Is there a way to only allow SQL Server 2014 syntax/functions to be used in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, compatibility-level

We're developing against SQL Server 2019 currently, but we have a need to deploy the same set of SQL scripts to a SQL Server 2014 database.

For example, in SQL Server 2019 a built-in function called `TRIM` exists but this is not supported in SQL Server 2014. To make sure we're only using syntaxes supported by both databases, I'm wondering if there's a solution to just allow 2014 syntaxes in 2019.

I thought altering compatibility mode of the database would have this effect, but this does not have the intended effect.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering if there's a solution to just allow 2014 syntaxes in 2019.

**No.** If you need your users to steer clear of things that won't work in versions newer than 2014, then **they should develop on 2014**.

At the very least, you could let them continue developing on 2019, but **automate scripting their objects to a 2014 instance**. You can't do this with backup/restore or detach/attach, but there are [plenty of ways to transfer objects/data to an older version](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/restoring-a-backup-to-an-older-version-of-sql-server). You'd also have to *run* all of the code, because some problems won't crop up until runtime.

**Compatibility level is not the answer here**, except for very rare exceptions (like `STRING_SPLIT`). Compatibility level is not used for allowing / disallowing syntax, in modern versions at least. See [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/01/sql-performance/compatibility-levels-and-cardinality-estimation-primer) and [this](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/database-compatibility-level-in-sql-server/). In older versions, yes, [a lot of syntax was controlled this way](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44912/1186), but that’s not how it works anymore.