# Clone a database from SQL Server 2019 to 2017

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

I try to clone a database from an Sql Server on my local machine v15 (2019) to a server machine v14(2017). I did a .bak file and when I tried to import on the server side it says:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server
> running version 15.00.4083. That version is incompatible with this
> server, which is running version 14.00.2037. Either restore the
> database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is
> compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Is there a "compatibility" backup mode on the 14-15 Sql Server versions?

local (on docker, Linux):

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB4583459) - 15.0.4083.2
> (X64)   Nov  2 2020 18:35:09   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft
> Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)

distant (on Windows Server)

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583456) - 14.0.2037.2 (X64)
> Nov  2 2020 19:19:59   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 
> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just succeeded to clone the Database, using on local: In the SSMS, right click *on the database to export*, then `Tasks` => `Export Data-tier Application` it creates a bacpac file.
[image]

Copy the backpac to the distant server, and there in SSMS, right click *on the "Databases" folder* and then `Import Data-tier Application`, use the copied backpac file.

It copies the schema and the data as well...

Comment: Yes **BACPAC** (schema and data) or **DACPAC** (if you just need the schema, no data) are the way to go when you need to migrate to an older version from a newer one. Glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Many thanks, this helped me out! For those curious as to why .bacpac is even smaller than a compressed .BAK, the difference is that the BAK also may save pending transactions, and the bacpac does not. See [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/diff-between-bak-and-backpac-files)